# How Select and view count rows from database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, singlestore

This is my controller : Admin

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $data['jumlah_instansi'] = $this->Dash_model->jml_instansi()->result(); 
    $this->load->view('Admin_view',$data);
}
}
```

This my model : Dash_model

```
public function jml_instansi()
{       
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM instansi");
    return $query->num_rows();
}}
```

This my view : Admin_view

```
<?php echo $jumlah_instansi; ?>
```

Please help me, sorry newbie..Thank you..

Thats show error 
Message: Undefined property: Admin::$Dash_model
Filename: controllers/Admin.php
and
Message: Call to a member function jml_instansi() on a non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first load a model before accessing it, e.g.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Dash_model');
    $data['jumlah_instansi'] = $this->Dash_model->jml_instansi()->result(); 
    // ...
}
```

See [Loading a Model](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model) for more.

Comment: thank you, how about error Message: Call to a member function result() on a non-object Filename: controllers/Admin.php ?

Comment: This is a subsequent error, because it doesn't recognize Dash_model.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.You are returning integer value of count so no need to use `result()` result set in controller.

Controller:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Dash_model');//load model
    $data['jumlah_instansi'] = $this->Dash_model->jml_instansi();
    $this->load->view('Admin_view',$data);
}
}
```

Model

```
public function jml_instansi()
{       
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM instansi");
    return $query->num_rows();
}}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $jumlah_instansi; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, thats work I remove result and add load dash model ..